# jsp read filename from servlet impossible?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filechooser

I've got a really simple problem.

I'm not able to read the file name from the (jsp) file-chooser in servlet.
Normally I can get any input data with request.getParameter("name");

Can anybody tell me the shortest way please?
this is my code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ImportServlet"> 
<td> <input type="file" size=20 name="fname"> </td> 
<td> <input type="Submit" value="Upload"> </td> </form>
```

thanks

Comment: do u have single file or multiple files...

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
request.getParameter("fname")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  MultipartRequest multiPartFile =new MultipartRequest(request,"targetDirectory");
  Enumeration files = multiPartFile.getFileNames();
  while(files.hasMoreElements() ){
      String fileName = (String)files.nextElement();
      System.out.println(fileName);
      String fileSystemName= multiPartFile.getFilesystemName(fileName );
      System.out.println(fileSystemName);
    }
```

Comment: No, my problem is to get this f...ing target directory. The User want to upload a file and gives the filename (path) of the file and I want to get the Path of the filename with the full path. I dont have a target directory because I will save the data in a mysql database. This all will be on localhost.

Comment: @user1844505 target directory is the directory name on the server side where you want to upload the file. I you want to upload in current directory then use `.`.

Comment: the is not a really "upload", all things are on localhost.

Comment: @user1844505 Doesn't matter. You are uploading the file from your local browser to your localhost server.

Comment: So, I will describe my problem again. I want to save From File To Database, there it is neccessary to get the full path, so I can not give a "targetDirectory" hardcoded. I hope you understand me

Comment: the problem is I've no access to the file/path, which was choosen with the filechooser.

Comment: @user1844505 Just try: `MultipartRequest multiPartFile =new MultipartRequest(request,".");`